# как сделать textarea адаптивным

Tags: html, css

Как сделать textarea адаптивным в тегах? Важно чтобы кнопка <kbd>Ok</kbd> была строго по центру напротив формы textarea и всесь этот блок был по центру

```css
.send {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="send">
  <table align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <form action="comments.php" method="post">
          <textarea placeholder="Написать комментарий." cols="55" rows="2" name="text"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td valign=top>
        <input value="Ok" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;" type="submit" /></form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Расположите для начала правильно тег form. Он у вас открывается в одном td, а закрывается в другом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.send {
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e3e4e8;
}
```

```html
<div class="send">
  <form action="comments.php" method="post">
    <table align="center">
      <tr>
        <td style="padding: 0 10px;">        
          <textarea placeholder="Написать комментарий." cols="55" rows="2" name="text" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
        </td>
        <td valign=top>
          <input value="Ok" style="width: 36px; height: 36px;" type="submit" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас теги неправильно стоят: form открывается в одном td, а закрывается в другом

Comment: @Yuri, спасибо, исправила, хотя не в этом суть)